# How to dealloc UnsafeMutablePointer referenced from Swift struct

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2

If I have a Swift struct like this:

```
struct ViewBox {
    let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>
    init() {
        pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>.alloc(1)
    }
}
```

how should I ensure, that the pointer is properly deallocated, when the struct is deallocated? I can't use `deinit` or `dealloc` methods for Swift structs.

Or I don't have to care and it's happening automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the pointer in a class. Something like this:

```
struct ViewBox {
    class WrappedPointer() {    
        let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>

        init() {
            pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>.alloc(1)
        }

        deinit {
            pointer.dealloc(1)
        }
    }

    let wrappedPointer = WrappedPointer()
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. So you think there is no direct way how to do that? :/

Comment: No, I don't think so.