# Swift version get wrong pixels data but the Object-c version get the right pixels data from the same image using method "CGBitmapContextCreate"

Tags: swift, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I can't believe my eyes, they are basically the same code, just convert the Object-c code to swift code, but the Object-c code always gets the right answer, but the swift code sometimes gets the right answer, sometimes gets wrong.

The Swift rendition:

```
class ImageProcessor1 {
    class func processImage(image: UIImage) {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return
        }
        let width = Int(image.size.width)
        let height = Int(image.size.height)
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4
        let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
        guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: imageData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
            return
        }
        imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
        print("---------data from Swift version----------")
        for i in 0..<width * height {
            print(imageData[i])
        }
    }
}
```

The Objective-C rendition:

```
- (UIImage *)processUsingPixels:(UIImage*)inputImage {

  // 1. Get the raw pixels of the image
  UInt32 * inputPixels;

  CGImageRef inputCGImage = [inputImage CGImage];
  NSUInteger inputWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
  NSUInteger inputHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
  NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

  NSUInteger inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth;

  inputPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));

  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight,
                                               bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                               kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);

    NSLog(@"---------data from Object-c version----------");
    UInt32 * currentPixel = inputPixels;
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < inputHeight; j++) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputWidth; i++) {
            UInt32 color = *currentPixel;
            NSLog(@"%u", color);
            currentPixel++;
        }
    }
  return inputImage;
}
```

Available at https://github.com/tuchangwei/Pixel

And if you get the same answer, please run it more times.

Comment: By the way, these code snippets don’t handle images whose [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale) is anything but `1`. You might consider handling scaling once you get the immediate question behind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your Objective-C and Swift code [have leaks](https://github.com/tuchangwei/Pixel/issues/1). Also your Swift code is not initializing the allocated memory. When I [initialized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer/2949348-initialize) the memory, I didn’t see any differences:

```
imageData.initialize(repeating: 0, count: width * height)
```

FWIW, while `allocate` doesn't initialize the memory buffer, the `calloc` does:

> ... The allocated memory is filled with bytes of value zero.

But personally, I’d suggest you get out of the business of allocating memory at all and pass `nil` for the `data` parameter and then use `bindMemory` to access that buffer. If you do that, as [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455939-init) says:

> Pass NULL if you want this function to allocate memory for the bitmap. This frees you from managing your own memory, which reduces memory leak issues.

Thus, perhaps:

```
class func processImage(image: UIImage) {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return
    }
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let bytesPerRow = width * 4

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    guard
        let imageContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo),
        let rawPointer = imageContext.data
    else {
        return
    }

    let pixelBuffer = rawPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: width * height)

    imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
    print("---------data from Swift version----------")
    for i in 0..<width * height {
        print(pixelBuffer[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks for your answer, it means a lot to me. It seems I can't release the `imageData` like

imageData.deinitialize(count: width*height)
imageData.deallocate()

Comment: Sorry, I haven't finished the comment...The reason is that I use `imageData` to create `pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)`. If I release imageData, then later, if I fetch pixel from `pixels`, I will get a crash. If I use `bindMemory `, I will get a crash too. Could you give me an analysis again? thanks.

Comment: Maybe I should release `pixels` after I don't need it like the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986292/how-to-dealloc-unsafemutablepointer-referenced-from-swift-struct. Thank you again.

Comment: There are a number of ways, but I’d avoid `allocate`/`deallocate` pattern. Perhaps give this method a closure parameter. Perhaps save it in a `Data`. But we’re going beyond the scope of this question; if you’re still unclear, maybe post a separate question. If/when you do, describe the broader problem you’re trying to solve, too.